# How to use 'Select-String' to filter lines from an output

Tags: powershell, select-string

(first of all, I have searched SO,internet,youtube, for half an hour and didn't came with proper answer so I ask here)

I'm coming from the realm of routers and helpesk when you can simply filter string\s from an output with

"| include" (cisco) or "| findstr" (windows)
like this:

[image: findstr]

I found out, on powershell we use 'Select-String' with the 'Pattern' switch.

For instance, i want to print out all the lines which contain the word 'Suffix'
but it doesn't seem to work.
What is the correct way, and can I use it without the need to creat a variable.

[image: powershell]

Comment: Can you include the text from the pictures in your question?

Comment: PLEASE, don't post images of code/errors/sample-data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 3):

Thank you both for clearing it out to me that the method retures objects in the form of array.

Unfortunately, I found working with 'Where-Object' and 'Select-Object' is complicated for this one time viewing purpose, so I converted the output to a string with the 'Out-String -Stream' cmdlet.

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "127.0.0.1"
```

It did the job well.

Comment: You do know that `Select-String` defaults to using a regex pattern if switch `-SimpleMatch` is not used, and that the pattern "127.0.0.1" contains dots, which have special meaning in regex (_any character_), do you? Without escaping those dots, a value of say "127X0Y0Z1" would also pass.. Rule of thumb: don't stringify an object to get one of its properties

Comment: Thank you for the important notice, I didn't took the time to lookup for the switches actions. @Theo

Answer (score 0):

[Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) is a cmdlet to find text in **strings** and **files**.
[Get-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress) does not output a string, but an array of (CimInstance) **objects**.

To select only certain values from this array, you can pipe the result through to `Select-Object` like for instance

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Select-Object Suffix*
```

which outputs something like:

```
SuffixOrigin
------------
        Link
        Link
   WellKnown
        Link
        Dhcp
   WellKnown
```

This output on its own is probably not very usefull though..
You might want to end up with selecting a few more properties like with

```
Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object IPAddress, InterfaceAlias, Suffix*
```

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlet `Get-NetIPAdress` returns an array of objects which can be filter with the cmdlet `Where-Object`. But the disadvantage is that you must choose the field for the filtering. There is a short example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps#example-5--get-ip-address-information-and-filter-the-output). Or you can use the cmdlet `Select-Object`:

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Select-Object *fix*
```

Otherwise you can also use the command `ipconfig` to be able to filtering your output:

```
ipconfig | Select-String -Pattern "fix"
```